# Script to disconnect PPPoE connected users

Tags: macos, pppoe

I connect via WLAN and a PPPoE connection to the internet. Unfortunatly, only 2 IP adresses are allowed at the same time.

Can I run a script to force a disconnect on all users of the PPPoE connection /WLAN?

I want to prevent people from keeping an IP address for hours.

Comment: Are the PPPoE users actually using their connection? and you want to disconnect them?  Or are we talking about a DHCP lease time issue here?

Comment: I want to disconnect all lets say every 3 hours to free up the ones not really using the connection